# How to save distance matrix in a local database?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, sqlite, google-maps

I have an application which works by referring the distance matrix. In the current design we are collecting the distance matrix from Google Maps v3 API, convert those to a hash and save into a local text file.

My data consists of distance between one point to another; I have 5000 points.

I am facing issues related to size. The file size is already 250MB.

1. What is the best way to store this kind of data?
2. Is there any way to get this much data fast?
3. How to search data from such a big list?

Comment: Since the data you are storing is actually just the result of some fairly simple lat/long math, wouldn't it be better to just store each point in the database with it's lat/long, and calculate the difference between two given points from those figures on request? Yes, it will slightly increase load times, but weigh that against the saving in data usage and I personally feel it is worth it.

Comment: How many records do you have in the table eating all the space? Can you post the schema of that table? Perhaps also a sample of records from that table?

Comment: Your tagged your post with PHP, MySQL, Perl and SQLite. Which specific combination of technologies are using in tihs application? Can you use other technologies to solve the problem, like PostgreSQL?

Comment: Define distance: linear or route. If it's linear then see @DaveRandom's comment. "my data consist of distance between one point to another and i have 5000 points.... 250MB" suggests that you've precalculated the distances between each point and every other, definitely change that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Google's [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) allow you store their data. See 10.1.3(b):

> You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.

A "temporary, secure" store which "does not permit use of Content outside of the Service" is basically the browser cache. It *might* include HTML5 local storage within the browser. It won't include any external database which allows the data to be used anywhere else. And 250MB is hardly "a limited amount"!

Nothing in the Distance Matrix documentation overrides this clause and allows storage of that data.

So: you are restricted to storing straight-line distances (provided you don't use the Google geocoder to find the locations).

I'm not entirely sure why Google are this restrictive; it's probably a result of their own licences from data providers.

---

So this isn't entirely doom and gloom, storing distance data is going to need a table with three columns: `origin`, `destination` and `distance`. Selecting one row from 5000 is going to be quick.